# Do any of the other rebels escape from the Battle of Hoth?

Tags: star-wars

Leia instructs the rebels to "meet at the rendez-vous point" after the battle of Hoth. Do any of the fighters or rebel leaders of the Echo Base make it out alive? (Besides our 6 heroes.)

Comment: "our 6 heroes" are important, but they could hardly sustain the rebellion by themselves.

Comment: We see a whole bantha load of transports successfully escaping. Are you asking whether they did? If so I can scrounge around a pic or video to prove it.

Comment: There's plenty of material here on the battle of Hoth; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Hoth according to the wiki, some 17 of 30 transports survived along with almost all of the senior rebel commanders.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That I what I was asking. Obviously the main characters can't sustain the rebellion alone-- I always assumed they had other locations.

Comment: @off topic, but I couldn't help but notice that the timing of your question coincides with a certain web comic... coincidence?

Comment: Richard is incorrect. Per *The Essential Guide to Warfare* (pg. 168), 17 of 30 were destroyed or captured, indicating that 13 made it through. Many of the commanders survived, including Carlist Rieekan, who appears in many EU works.

Answer (score 8):

Speaking strictly G-Canon, I can think of one survivor right off the top of my head: [Wedge Antilles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles).

Wedge was one of the Rogue Squadron pilots who piloted the Snowspeeders during the Battle of Hoth.

[image: Wedge on Hoth]

He then participates in the attack on the second Death Star.

[image: Wedge before the attack on the second Death Star]

He even survives that battle and celebrates with our main heroes on the forest moon.

[image: Wedge and Han]

It can also be noted that he participated in the Battle of Yavin as part of Red Squadron.

---

In C-Canon, [Toryn Farr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Toryn_Farr) springs to mind.

Toryn was one of the communication operators in Echo Base. She survives and appears in one of the Tales of the Bounty Hunters stories. This story, [Of Possible Futures: The Tale of Zuckuss and 4-Lom](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Of_Possible_Futures:_The_Tale_of_Zuckuss_and_4-LOM) describes portions of the evacuation from an alternate point of view.

[image: Toryn Farr]